# Checking a radiobutton if a button is clicked

Tags: c#

How can I make it so that when I click a button, it checks a radiobutton? I'm trying to make it so that a radiobox is checked when the button is clicked

Comment: Downvote 'cause this is (in my opinion) a "I'm lazy gimme code"-Question, which should not be here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainWindow()
{
       // This button needs to exist on your form.
       //Bind your button click event, this event will be triggered when button is clicked.
       myButton.Click += myButton_Click;
}

//Once the button is clicked, now you can set the Checked property of your boolean.
void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    radioButton.Checked = true;
}
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: @Drenmi added a bit of explanation

Answer (score 0):

Did you even tried it yourself?

You just have to set the `IsChecked`-Property of your Radiobutton in the `Click`-Eventhandler of the Button.

Answer (score 0):

You can add next line in on click event of the button:

```
radioButton.Checked = true;
```

Comment: This isn't the wanted behavior.